# check if filenames already exist in formdata object not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-file-upload, form-data

I have multiple input file fields and other input form fields.I use ajax for file uploading and form submit.My jquery code is like this.

```
$.fn.serializefiles = function() {
    var obj = $(this);

    var form_data = new FormData(this[0]);
   //appending all files to form_data

    $.each($(obj).find('.file'), function(i, tag) {
    //here I need to check if files are same,if same files are there,only upload one file
        $.each($(tag)[0].files, function(i, file) {
            if((file.length>0)&&(!in_array(file.name,form_data)))
                form_data.append(tag.name, file);
        });
    });

   //appending all input fields to form_data 
   var params = $(obj).serializeArray();
   //I need to add input fields which are not in form_data.This works fine
    $.each(params, function (i, val) {
        if(val.name!='file')
        {
            //console.log(val.name+'<br/>');
            form_data.append(val.name, val.value);
        }
    });

    return form_data;
};
```

Initially I am adding all files to formdata.Here I need to append non empty files which are not in formdata object.

Also in the second section I am adding all input fields of form to formdata object.Here I need to append input fields which are not file types since I have appended file fields in the previous block of code.The second block works fine.
I need to allow to add only one file to formdata object if file input has same filenames

Comment: Is `in_array` your custom function?

Comment: no....jquery in_array()

Comment: @mic4ael how to check if filename is in formdata object

Comment: I have used form_data.getAll('file'),this is also not working@mic4ael

Comment: jQuery uses `jQuery.inArray` function and not `in_array`

Comment: Then also I am gettind duplicate files @mic4ael